# Custom/vanity domain name configuration in Exchange Online

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, outlook-web-app, autodiscovery, exchangeonline

Currently, when users 'Add account' in Microsoft Outlook 2016, the users are automatically configured (possibly through autodiscovery) to connect to 'https://outlook.office365.com/mapi/nspi/?MailboxId=xxx-yyy-zzz@contoso.com' exchange server.

However, I would like them to be automatically configured to connect through our vanity URL, like 'https://exchange.server.consoto.com/mapi/nspi/?MailboxId=xxx-yyy-zzz@contoso.com'.

And I would like the same:

1) For SMTP: it should be smtp.contoso.com:587 **instead of** smtp.office365.com:587

2) For POP, IMAP and Exchange Online: it should be exchange.server.contoso.com **instead of** outlook.office365.com (with the respective ports)

3) For OWA: it should be https://outlook.contoso.com/owa/ **instead of** https://outlook.office.com/owa/

How can this be configured?

Thanking you,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your own URLs, then you need to deploy an on premise server. Nothing you want to do is possible with Office365.